# This iPhone 6s is running iOS 11.1.2 (15B202), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am running Xcode 8.3.2 and getting this error when I am trying to run an application on my iOS 11.1.2 device. The solution I found is to update Xcode. For that I have to update my macOS. I am actually on a travel and I am looking for a solution that doesn't require a good internet connection. Will it work if I just update the device support files? and if so, where can I find them? I looked everywhere on the Apple website but I was not able to find them.

Comment: You can just add device support files to your current Xcode  ( size ~ 6M). But as @TomHarrington wrote it is distributed only with new version of Xcode. Write me if you still need them, probably I can share them to you.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution is updating your Xcode. The latest version of Xcode is 9.2.

Comment: Adding the ios 11.2.1 device support files will not work?

Comment: @user567 The only place to get the device support files is from an installation of Xcode 9.2.

Comment: As rmaddy told, the only solution is to install the Xcode 9.2

Answer (score 1):

You can either update Xcode or install the device support files. However, to get the device support files, you need to download the newest version of Xcode. You don't necessarily have to install it, but you have to get it, because those files are not distributed outside of Xcode.

If your internet connection is poor, that's a problem, but this is how Apple does it. Either approach requires at least downloading Xcode.